# Magento causing css issue after merging in safari

Tags: magento-1.9, css, merge-css

Magento merged css causes issue in safari browser and works well in other browser. Any one could give some idea? no error found in console.

Without merging it is working well.

Comment: It would be easier if you could specify what kind of issues you found? Are those css-only issues and could be reproduced? Can you give us an example?

Comment: e.g. first i had a horizontal menu now after merging it is not showing horizontally. It is showing randomly no format. And it is fine with other browser. Ya mainly css issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried clearing browser cache.

For safari, you can find under Develop->Empty Caches.

Or otherwise try in private safari and check.

Comment: Ya i tried. but result is still the same

Comment: Did you tried in private window too?

Comment: yes. but result is same.

Comment: Try deleting all files under media/css and clear everything under var/cache and try.

Comment: Tried. still same. Now i am playing to combine js and css as per page and not entire. Do you have idea will it be good for optimization